# Factory Girl uninitialized constant NameError in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I am trying to use Factory Girl to generate model instances that have polymorphic dependents.  For example, Properties can have_one Assumption, and Tenants can have_one Assumption, and Properties can have_many Tenants. I would like to use Factory Girl to generate a :property_with_assumption or a :tenant_with_assumption.

I can do that with Properties without a problem:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :property do
    ...fields...
  end

    factory :property_with_assumption do
      after(:create) do |property|
        FactoryGirl.create(:assumption, assumable: property)
      end
    end
end
```

And I have a similar definition for Tenants:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :tenant, :class => 'Tenant' do
    ...fields...
  end

  factory :tenant_with_assumption do
    after(:create) do |tenant|
      FactoryGirl.create(:assumption, assumable: tenant)
    end
  end
end
```

But when I try

```
FactoryGirl.create(:tenant_with_assumption, property: [valid property])
```

I get

```
NameError: uninitialized constant TenantWithAssumption
```

Why does it work for one model but not the other?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide the `:class` parameter:

```
factory :tenant_with_assumption, :class => 'Tenant' do
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Why do I need the :class parameter on Tenants but not Properties?

Comment: `:property_with_assumption` won't work either. You're probably not calling it anywhere. If the factory name is not the same as the underscored version of the class name you need to provide the `:class` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in a nested way as well.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :tenant, :class => 'Tenant' do
    ...fields...


    factory :tenant_with_assumption do
      after(:create) do |tenant|
        FactoryGirl.create(:assumption, assumable: tenant)
      end
    end
  end
end
```